# Sql Query to find missing monthly payment

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL Table with Monthly installments from group members.

```
Member A : 10 ( Monthly Fee),
Member B : 15 ( Monthly Fee )
```

My Database Table

[image: My Database Table]

I am looking for a query which can return as follows.
I need to get result as seen in the pic to find missing payment

[image: I need to get result as see in the pic to find missing payment]

Comment: Do you consider year also?

Comment: Is it possible to, for example, receive a December 2016 payment recording in January 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example data and desired output you can use `PIVOT` though I would always recommend to `PIVOT` your data in your presentation application rather than in a database query.

```
USE
tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('Payments', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Payments
GO

CREATE TABLE Payments(
   Serial# INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Date   DATE  NOT NULL
  ,MemberName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Month  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,MonthlyFee INT  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (1,'01/01/2017','Member A','January',10);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (2,'01/01/2017','Member B','January',15);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (3,'01/02/2017','Member A','February',10);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (4,'01/03/2017','Member B','March',15);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (5,'01/03/2017','Member A','March',10);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (6,'01/05/2017','Member A','May',10);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (7,'01/06/2017','Member A','June',10);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (8,'01/05/2017','Member B','May',15);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (9,'01/09/2017','Member A','September',10);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (10,'01/06/2017','Member B','June',15);
INSERT INTO Payments(Serial#,Date,MemberName,Month,MonthlyFee) VALUES (11,'01/10/2017','Member A','October',10);

SELECT
    MemberName
,   January
,   February
,   March
,   April
,   May
,   June
,   July
,   August
,   September
,   October
,   November
,   December

FROM
(
    SELECT
        MemberName
    ,   Month
    ,   MonthlyFee

    FROM
        Payments
) AS P

PIVOT
(
    SUM(MonthlyFee)
    FOR [Month] IN
    (
        January
    ,   February
    ,   March
    ,   April
    ,   May
    ,   June
    ,   July
    ,   August
    ,   September
    ,   October
    ,   November
    ,   December
    )
) AS Pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic list of column names, Not much different from mheptinstall's approach

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((select top (12) ','+QuoteName(DateName(MONTH,(DateAdd(MM, Row_Number() over(order by (Select NULL))-1, '2017-01-01')))) 
    from master..spt_values for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Select @query = ' Select * from (
    Select MemberName, [Month], MonthlyFee from Payments ) a
    pivot(sum(MonthlyFee) for [Month] in ('+ @cols1 + ') ) p '

Exec SP_ExecuteSql @query
```